# Reflection c# in a set property

Tags: c#, reflection, types, properties, set

Why can't I use the value word in a set property when i'm trying to get the type of the value?

```
set
    {
        Type t = value.GetType();

        if (dictionaries[int.Parse(value.GetType().ToString())] == null)
        {
            dictionaries[int.Parse(value.GetType().ToString())] = new Dictionary<string,t>();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't recognize the word t in my Dictionary constructor.
what am I doing wrong? how can I solve it?

Comment: can you provide your complete property definition?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use values or names of types as generic type parameters. Use a method with a generic type parameter instead:

```
void SetDict<T>(T value)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    if (dictionaries[t.FullName] == null)
    {
        dictionaries[t.FullName] = new Dictionary<string,T>();
    }
}
```

Instead of using the type name, you can also use the `Type` value as a key directly for dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string,T>> dictionaries;
```

You can call it without specifying the generic type parameter, because the compiler can infer the type. However, this works only for the static type, not for the runtime type. I.e. you must call the method with an expression of the right type and not through a base type like `object`.

```
SetDict("hello"); // ==> string type
SetDict(42); // ==> int type

object obj = "world";
SetDict(obj); // ==> object type, not string type!
```

---

Note: Generic type parameters allow you to create strongly typed specialized types and methods at compile time. The advantage of strong typing lies in the fact that the compiler and the IDE can give you information on a type and certify that your code is statically correct AT COMPILE TIME. Creating a generic type at RUNTIME has no advantage, as you won't be able to use its advantages at compile time (or design time, if you prefer). You can as well use a `Dictionary<string, object>` or the like.

Please see my answer on code review: [Type-safe Dictionary for various types](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12292/9810). Especially my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `Type` *variable* when declaring a generic type, you have to use an actual type.

In other words, this won't work:

```
Type t = ....
var x = new Dictionary<string, t>();
```

Depending on your class, you could do this:

```
public class Something<T>
{
    public T Value
    {
        ...
        set
        {
            ... new Dictionary<string, T>();
        }
    }
}
```

but that's not quite the same.

You also got a different problem, this:

```
int.Parse(value.GetType().ToString())
```

will not work.

```
value.GetType().ToString()
```

will likely produce something like `System.Int32` or `YourAssembly.NameSpace.SomeType`, not a number that can be parsed.

I think you need to take one step back, and figure out what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I solved the problem that you said i can't solve (I don't need to use an actual type). and about the int.parse()- i know- I already fixed it, I didn't ask about it because it's not full. now I have another problem- I can't specify the type for the property because it's unknown. I don't know if there's a solution :|